# 'gulp watch' Syntax error unexpected token illegal v3.8.10

Tags: coffeescript, npm, gulp

I updated gulp and this is what I am getting now when I try 'gulp watch'

CLI version 3.8.10
Local version 3.8.10

Image of error:
http://s3.postimg.org/e6usiz1k3/issue.png

Comment: What does the gulpfile look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your `gulpfile.coffee` is being interpreted as a JavaScript file. Node complains about the first comment - `#` is not a valid character in JS.

A while ago, the proposed solution by the gulp folks to use CoffeeScript was to use a `gulpfile.js` that requires CoffeeScript and your `gulpfile.js`. For example, the approach discussed here: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/103

However, it seems that since 3.7 transpilers are automagically detected, as long as they are installed in your `node_modules/`. See https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/ae98edfbfbe8341f20c7cb5d4d4b8ec339ee44ae/CHANGELOG.md#370

> added support for transpilers via liftoff 0.11 and interpret just npm
>   install your compiler (coffee-script for example) and it will work out
>   of the box

So you should

- Check that your gulp is more recent than 3.7 with `npm ls`
- Try running `npm install coffee-script`